# HTTParty: Changing authentication types per instance (ie toggling basic and digest auths) causes an Argument Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api-design, httparty

Depending on a particular device type, we will toggle between basic auth (default) to digest auth.

When implementing this decision, getting this error:

```
ArgumentError: only one authentication method, :basic_auth or :digest_auth may be used at a time
```

If forced to basic only - works fine. Including HTTParty in both client classes.  And including it in the parent class for a particular request that is device specific.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the crux of this is that `HTTParty` is not thread-safe and thus those instances are shared across classes and thus why you cannot change lower-level configuration changes.

Honestly I ditched HTTParty because of this and moved to RestClient which is more full-featured.

Answer (score 0):

So...after digging into their gem, it appears they build a basic auth right at the start when initializing the Request class - even with a digest auth hash present in the options.

There is no consideration to checking the options, just parse the url for the credentials and immediately build a basic auth in the options for the Request. This gets you to the error above.

Putting a condition to check for pre-existing auths in my local project for the initialize method solved my problem.